# How to pass an argument to a Core Data life cycle method?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

It seems like the Core Data life cycle methods need to be overridden in the subclass of `NSManagedObject`. I have deletion features in various parts of my app, in the main view controller, the detail view controller, etc, and some of them require conditional statements depending on the state of the property within the view controller. How do I use it in a view controller or pass an argument to the `prepareForDeletion` method?

When I generate the subclass of NSMangedObject through the "Create NSManagedObject subclass" feature, the subclass files are created so that they exist separately from the view controllers.

```swift
override func prepareForDeletion() {
    super.prepareForDeletion()
    
    if filePath != nil {
        // logic
    } else {
        print("filepath is empty")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is filepath the thing you want to pass or a property of your Entity?

Comment: I want to pass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func prepareForDeletion()` is used to propagate custom changes across the database when deleting an object.

Don't put UI level decision logic inside your data layer.

As `filePath` is probably part of the UI you can either repeat the logic in each place or condense to a logic object somewhere if there's enough commonality in the delete actions.

```
class DatabaseDecisions {

    @discardableResult func delete(_ thing: Thing, filePath: String?) -> Bool {
        if filePath != nil {
            // logic
        } else {
            print("filepath is empty")
        }
        return didIReallyDeleteIt
    }
}
```

Then at UI level e.g in your view controller

```
func deleteAction(_ sender: Any) {
     let thing = selectedThing()
     DatabaseDecisions().delete(thing, filePath: filePath)
}
```

**EDIT**

To have side effects on a property set you can use `didSet` like with any other property.

```
extension Thing {
    public override var filePath: String? {
        didSet {
            //logic to cleanup files
        }
    }
}
```

But again possibly this logic is better left outside the data layer and cleanup ops delegated to external logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Let's say `filePath` is a property of an entity and it gets fetched and modified, is there a life cycle method that get triggered to delete the previous file? For example `filePath = "A"` is fetched and updated to `filePath = "B"`, I want the file located at "A" to be deleted.